# turning physics on and off

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit, collision-detection

I'm trying to solving a problem where a sprite node can jump up through a platform but cannot jump back down. I tried using this code:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    if (thePlayer.position.y > stonePlatform1.position.y) ==  true {
        stonePlatform1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: stonePlatform.size.width * 0.9, height: stonePlatform.size.height * 0.75))
        stonePlatform1.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
        stonePlatform1.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
        stonePlatform1.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = BodyType.object.rawValue
        stonePlatform1.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.object.rawValue
        stonePlatform1.physicsBody!.restitution = 0.4
    }
}
```

The idea was to turn on the physics body of the platform on when the player is above the platform. However, the physics doesn't work at all when I use this code. In fact I tried using this code:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    if (thePlayer.position.y < stonePlatform1.position.y) ==  true {
        stonePlatform1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: stonePlatform.size.width * 0.9, height: stonePlatform.size.height * 0.75))
        stonePlatform1.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
        stonePlatform1.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
        stonePlatform1.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = BodyType.object.rawValue
        stonePlatform1.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.object.rawValue
        stonePlatform1.physicsBody!.restitution = 0.4
    }
}
```

and the physics doesn't turn on either. If the IF statement isn't there, the physics does work all of the time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the node velocity for this platforms, like this:

SpriteKit - Swift 3 code:

```
private var up1 : SKSpriteNode!
private var down1 : SKSpriteNode!
private var down2 : SKSpriteNode!
private var player : SKSpriteNode!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    up1 = self.childNode(withName: "up1") as! SKSpriteNode
    down1 = self.childNode(withName: "down1") as! SKSpriteNode
    down2 = self.childNode(withName: "down2") as! SKSpriteNode
    player = self.childNode(withName: "player") as! SKSpriteNode
    up1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0b0001 // Mask for UoPlatforms
    down1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0b0010 // Mask for downPlatforms
    down2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0b0010 // Same mask
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0b0000 // Reset the mask

    // For UP only Platform
    if (player.physicsBody?.velocity.dy)! < CGFloat(0.0) {
        player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask |= 0b0001 // The pipe | operator adds the mask by binary operations
    }

    // For Down only platforms
    if (player.physicsBody?.velocity.dy)! > CGFloat(0.0) {
        player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask |= 0b0010  // The pipe | operator adds the mask by binary operations
    }

}
```

Source code with example here: https://github.com/Maetschl/SpriteKitExamples/tree/master/PlatformTest

The example show this:
Green platforms -> Down Only
Red platforms -> Up only

[image]

Comment: not a bad solution but it doesn't solve the problem of what happens when the block stops moving inside another block

Comment: Plus 1 just for the `|=`.  That is great.

Comment: @PierreCourpron with this implementation the block it's pushed by engine outside of platform. What behavior are you looking for?

Comment: | isn't a pipe character, it's a a bitwise OR. See here for turning on or off individual contacts & collisions via flipping individual bit int he contactTest or collision bitmasks - http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sprite-kit/6261/sknode-collision/29418/manipulating-contacttest-and-collison-bitmasks-to-enable-disable-specific-contac#t=201704240835269262745

Answer (score 0):

You could try just starting with the physics body as `nil` and then set the physics values to it after the player is above it. Also, this kind of code should be in the update function.  Having it in didMove only lets it get called once.

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval){
 if (thePlayer.position.y < stonePlatform1.position.y) && stonePlatform1.physicsBody != nil {
       stonePlatform1.physicsBody = nil
 }else if (thePlayer.position.y > stonePlatform1.position.y) && stonePlatform1.physicsBody == nil{
    setPhysicsOnPlatform(stonePlatform1)
 }
}

func setPhysicsOnPlatform(_ platform: SKSpriteNode){
   platform.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: stonePlatform.size.width * 0.9, height: stonePlatform.size.height * 0.75))
   ...
   //the rest of your physics settings
}
```

You should also do some handling for the height of the player and your anchorPoint. Otherwise if your anchorPoint is (0,0) and the player is halfway through the platform, the physics will be applied and a undesirable result will occur.

Comment: Why not simply play with the collisionBitMask instead of recreating the physicsbody every time?

Comment: I have done that before as well, but i've always had better look with the entire body.  Furthermore, scenarios like this usually involve needing multiple values changed, such as contactTest, collision, mass, etc.  Doing it this way solves all of that.

Comment: Doing that will ruin collision for something else.  What if an enemy is walking there?  It will fall as the player's pass through.  There must be a simpler way of doing it.  Just enclose the value changes in functions.  It will be more cpu efficient too.

Comment: @BadgerBadger how would you do something like that?

Comment: Just a quick idea like that: build an array of all those platforms.  When the player is moving, calculate the movement angle.  The only moment where you need the platforms to let the player pass is if he is moving upward.  Use the angle to determine if he does or not and use the array with the platforms to update the bitmask accordingly.  If the player is moving up, remove the player from the colision bitmask, if he is moving down, add the player to the bitmask, unless he is already making contact with a platform: this will avoid having the platform become solid while overlapping the character

Comment: Note that bitmasks should be manipulated with bitwise operators: &&, ||, etc.